# az aks install-connector fails with "--name unknown parameter"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install a test Kubernetes cluster.  I the latest version of Azure CLI on my computer along with the latest Helm.  When I run the command:

```
az aks install-connector --name MyManagedCluster --resource-group MyResourceGroup --connector-name virtual-kubelet --os-type Both
```

I get the error:

```
Deploying the ACI connector for 'Linux' using Helm
Error: unknown flag: --name
Deploying the ACI connector for 'Windows' using Helm
Error: unknown flag: --name
```

It appears that "az aks install-connector" is generating a badly formed command for helm.  Can anyone shed light on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused by helm 3. Actually the CLI command `az aks install-connector` will use helm 3 to install the chart that shows in it. But the helm 3 does not have the flag `--name`, see the [helm 3 commands](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#options). So it will cause the error:

> Error: unknown flag: --name

You can see the flag `--name` in [helm 2 commands](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/helm/#options-21).

The solution is that you can skip the CLI command and use the helm 3 directly to install the chart in the AKS cluster. And you can find the chart in the parameter `--chart-url` of the CLI command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-install-connector). Or use the helm 2 instead of helm 3.

Comment: I reverted to Helm 2.  Once that was configured, the "az aks install-connector" worked.